# is using sha1() with a salt secure?

Tags: php, security, hash, sha1, password-protection

I understand that sha1() is not secured, but my client's website uses something like this to hash passwords:

```
$salt = '123abckkk';
$hash = sha1($salt.$password);
```

Now I'm guessing that if someone breaks into the database and steals the hashes, then they won't be able to crack them because none of the hashes would have come from common words, because they have that '123abckkk' mixed up in it.

Not sure if this is how it works, but if this is not a secure method then please tell me why.

Comment: So are you saying that the attacker will figure out the salt and will be able to separate the salt from the password?

Comment: Also read, [Why are common hashing functions such as md5() and sha1() unsuitable for passwords?](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash)

Comment: You can  use sha1() function with salt.salt will genearate random

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. [You should not use `md5` or `sha1` to hash passwords](http://www.php.net/manual/en/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash), instead use [`password_hash`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php).

   - Hashing passwords isn't for your security. It's for your user's security. We're assuming an attacker has a dump of your database and has a long time to reverse the hash into passwords. The longer the hashing function takes, the longer it takes for the attacker to crack these passwords. The time delaying them can be used to warn your users and tell them to change their passwords on different networks.
2. Hashes should be **unique** and not a set string such as `123abckkk`.

   - If two passwords are the same, they will have the same hash. If one password is cracked, everyone else with the same password will also be cracked. This also prevents any rainbow tables from being generated. (See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rainbow_table#Defense_against_rainbow_tables)